# ruby irb stops outputting suddenly

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I'm learning automation using Watir.

When I do in powershell using Interactive Ruby (irb), irb stops outputting after sometime. And it is not a line number issue.

irb(main):025:1> br.present?
irb(main):026:1> br.exists?
(Just a sample how it looks when irb stops responding and br is the browser instance here)

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried making a script of this and see if it is somehow a coding error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:1` in the command prompt means you're nested one level deep - you need to close off the block you're inside with a `}` or an `end`.